# ACRA init crashing after new rom flash

Tags: custom-roms, crashes, cyanogenmod

I recently flashed CM11 on my GS2, it was slimkat 4.4.2 earlier. I believe I did a dirty flash because all my apps and settings were present when I booted it. I used the "recommended" wipe on TWRP.

Some apps gave issues (particularly settings > developer) but wiping app data fixed that. However some apps, watchdog lite in particular is having crashes before it starts (everytime). From logcat, this looks to be due to ACRA init. Clear app data or even app reinstall doesnt fix it. Anyone have any idea?

The lowest exception I see is

```
E/ACRA    (10931): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/ACRA    (10931):      at org.acra.ConfigurationInspector.toString(ConfigurationInspector.java:129)
E/ACRA    (10931):      at org.acra.ErrorReporter.init(ErrorReporter.java:363)
E/ACRA    (10931):      at org.acra.ACRA.initAcra(ACRA.java:297)
E/ACRA    (10931):      at org.acra.ACRA.init(ACRA.java:238)
E/ACRA    (10931):      at com.zomut.watchdog.library.WatchdogApp.onCreate(WatchdogApp.java:31)
E/ACRA    (10931):      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
E/ACRA    (10931):      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4468)
```

This is for both Watchdog and Travel pocket, the other app that crashes. Any idea if I need to clear files on the SD card or something?

Is this the right forum for it? Or Superuser? or SO?

Comment: In my opinion, this is a valid end-user problem. I see no cause to migrate, although SO has more proficient users in stacktracing&debugging.

Comment: @onik I actually was thinking (perhaps selfishly) more in the lines of who might have the expertise to answer